# Android Data-Binding : Example vs Reality

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

In all the data-binding examples that shows `Generic` data type handling [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#collections) uses real char `<` and `>`.

[image]

but when it comes to reality

[image]

I am getting below error.

> The value of attribute "type" associated with an element type
>   "variable" must not contain the '<' character.

I've searched the web and found people use `&gt;` for `>` and `&lt;` for `<` as a fix.

[image]

**Questions**

1. Is this supposed to happen ? If yes why it's not mentioned in the docs ?
2. Is there any fix for this, where I can write the layout as given in the official docs? (without using corresponding html entity characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now they've updated the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions)

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's unlikely to be a change to this because layout files are still XML, this isn't really the fault of Android or DataBinding, you're going to need to use appropriate encoding for HTML entities within an XML document.

Using `&lt;` isn't that terrible as a fix, as far as resolutions go, but if you'd rather avoid using it, then it may be an option to simplify your binding expressions to move logic away from the layout and into your variables.

The current advised method of doing so is with a ViewModel, which can be bound to the layout and expose observable LiveData values.

I can't give you a reason for it not being in the documentation besides that it's probably just not advised to do so.